# Django continue with next object in for loop when if statement applies

Tags: python, django, for-loop

My Django application needs to have a transaction refund function.
therefor I created the following snipped at admin.py:

```
def mark_refunded(modeladmin, request, queryset):
    for transaction in queryset.all():
        if transaction.status == 2:
            messages.error(request, 'Trx. ' + str(transaction.trx_id) + ' has already been refunded, skipping.')
        if transaction.fee:
            messages.error(request, 'Trx. ' + str(transaction.trx_id) + ' cannot be refunded as fees are not refundable!')

        elif do XYZ with the transaction ...   

        return request
```

Now I want my for loop to continue with the next item in the loop as soon as one of the above mentioned if statements do apply, who can that be accomplished?
Currently it seems that the object(s) gets processed anyways, even when my if statement applies which also makes sense to me as I don't have "return request" at my if statement.
In the end I want to process multiple transaction objects with a single queryset action. As soon as one of the two if statements do apply, the specific object should get skipped and the for loop should continue with the next item

full code at: https://pastebin.com/fiUvTnzQ

Thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe make the second `if` an `elif`. If that is not possible, then add a `continue` to each of the first two `if`.

Comment: Okay but is that even possible, dont I need a iter list for this to work? Or do I now mix things up with the next statement?

Comment: Could you please elaborate as to what you think may not work. Also, do you want to return from the function as soon as you find the first element that does not satisfy both if statements

Comment: Lets say you have multiple transaction objects at your Django admin and you want to mark them all as refunded, currently this applies even if a transaction object in the queryset hits one of the conditional if statements

Comment: Yeah, so when you add a `continue` to both the `if` statements, whenever a transaction is already refunded or cannot be refunded, it will go into the `if` block and then back to the for loop due to the `continue`. So it won't reach the `do XYZ with the transaction ...` part

Comment: Even with continue statement in place this fails and other transactions in my queryset don't get touched. But yes I would expect the same as you

Comment: Check the `return` once. You have placed it within the for loop. So it is returning after it finds the first element that does not satisfy both if statements. Place the return outside the for loop and check maybe

Comment: My current situation is like this: https://pastebin.com/fiUvTnzQ
But no matter where i place my return statement all transaction in my queryset are getting refunded, why that?

Comment: You would have better luck posting this as a new question

Comment: I start to think that my whole issue is coming form queryset.update(status=2) as this would include all transaction objects at my queryset ... I guess that I have to update the transaction and not go over the global queryset.update statement

Comment: Okay works ... Thanks for the help!